# Cannot start AVD emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just can't work with AVD emulator in Eclipse. I create an AVD but it takes forever to show the home screen. It just shows a black screen with the 'android' logo.

I am using target-18, CPU/ABI-ARM(armeabi-v7a), RAM-1400.

Can anyone please suggest what to do in this case?

I have seen previous answers on SO, but all the answers suggest to increase RAM but still no success in my case.

Comment: what is eclipse emulator?  my eclipse is slow as hell,  i wonder how fast is eclipse emulator..

Answer (score 1):

Same problem exist for me if you provide RAM-1400 it will aquire yyour RAm so automatically your system will slow down, use this settings, it will be really super fast.

Recommended:

1. Device: Nexus S(4" 480 x 800; hdpi)
2. Target: (2.3.3 API Level 9)  or (5.0 API Level
   20)
3. CPU/ABI: ARM
4. Skin: HVGA
5. RAM: 343
6. VM HEAP: 32
7. Internal Storage: max 200

Answer (score 1):

```
* Close Eclipse
* Kill adb through command line with command adb kill-server
* Now start task manager and kill adb process also from there if running from the process tab
```

*  Now start your adb again from command line with adb start-server
   *  Now start your Eclipse again and run your application

Answer (score 0):

AVD emulator got bad reputation for its problems and being so slow.

I would recommend trying Genymotion emulator. Its fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Eclipse` version for `Windows`, specify RAM with a value greater than 1024MB will not work. Try setting RAM to a lower value like 512MB and so on.

Also, let your own graphic card renders the AVD emulator by selecting **Use Host GPU**. This will save some memory (RAM) as modern graphic cards have their own onboard GPU+RAM to allow them to render graphic objects more efficiently.

Comment: This is incorrect: "specify RAM with a value greater than 1024MB will not work".  The RAM limit you refer to is (I think) the Java heap size limit which (1) is not actually 1024MB but a value that varies from system to system (according to what DLL versions you have installed) and is usually about 1100MB, (2) only applies to 32-bit windows, and (3) is totally unrelated to the  android emulator, which is able to use up to 2GB on any system that has enough RAM.